# Hard Drive Issue

Tags: hard-drive, hardware

I was using a dual boot system (ubuntu/windows7) and suddenly it was not working properly. I tried to install a fresh OS but not able to do so and when I went to service centre they told me that your Hard Disk got damaged and need to replace it.
It was also taking too long while installing a new issue. I installed somehow windows 10 but after installing getting an I/O error attached in below image. After that I live booted the Ubuntu and checked the disk there I was also getting SELF-TEST-FAILED error in Ubuntu(screen shot attached below).

Please confirm that the hard disk is really got damaged and only option I have is to replace it.

[Error for Windows10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j3qB.jpg)

[Error for Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DT8l.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Self-Test Failed` and `I/O Error` messages are ***usually*** the sign of a breaking or about-to-break hard drive.

There are cases where these errors actually don't mean that the hard drive is toast (have you made sure the drive and all cables are securely fastened), but these are pretty rare.

Without seeing more information, like detailed SMART status, there's no way to tell for sure, but chances are that your hard drive is sadly gone.

Comment: @AjayYadav If my answer solved your problem and you are satisfied with it, please click the grey checkmark to the left of the post. This marks the post as "solved" and allows other people to find it easier. And, it gives you +2 reputation!